# Recreating previously created dynamic components using Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-components

I am creating components dynamically using the code below:

```
components = {}
....
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentClass);
const component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

// Push the component so that we can keep track of which components are created
this.components[pageNumber].push(component);
```

Now, I am trying to mimic multi page form behaviour, so when the user clicks "Next Page", I clear the container using this.container.clear() and repopulate it using the new page's components.

That's all working fine and I have a list of components created on every page. However, I am stuck on what to do if the user clicks the "Previous Page" button. I am not sure how to repopulate the container using the components stored in the this.components object?

I cannot push fresh components again, as their values can be modified by the user, and recreating it would reset all the values.

Is this the correct approach, or should I look into it in a different way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting approach with dynamic components. Did you try detach() and insert() methods of ViewContainerRef, like below -

```
const viewRef = this.container.detach();
this.viewRefs[pageNumber].push(viewRef);

// after coming back to the page
this.container.insert(this.viewRefs[pageNumber].pop());
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like the correct path. I tried though, and it is returning only the last component from the view when I insert it again. Let me check and I will update the comment soon. Thanks

Comment: Edit: Just found that detach needs an index, else it only inserts the last view in the container :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, thanks to the code from Uday Vunnam below. Here is the final working code. I will accept Uday's answer though, as it led me to the right path and saved me from writing a lot of unnecessary code!

Initially,

```
this.viewRefs = {}
```

For detaching the views from the container:

```
this.viewRefs[this.currPage] = [];
//The line below was added as the container pops values mid-loop, disturbing the length
let containerLength = this.container.length;
for(let i=0; i<containerLength; i++){
  //Detach the 0 index always, as the container values are being popped put internally.
  this.viewRefs[this.currPage].push(this.container.detach(0));
}
```

For attaching views in the new page:

```
for(let i=0; i<this.viewRefs[this.currPage].length; i++){
  this.container.insert(this.viewRefs[this.currPage][i])
}
```